# Connecting to a Database using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I know its a basic question but no one has asked it so i am asking probably everyone knows it.

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection.
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
With cnn
    .ConnectionString = "Driver=SQL Server;Server=something;Uid=something;PWD=something!;Database=CS"
    .ConnectionTimeout = 60
    .Open
End With
```

Ok so here i have a doubt where do we define the actual existence of the database?

i mean how will the code know where is the DB? we need to give some path reference right?

The above code opens the connection and keeps it ready but where is the DB how does the code know?

Comment: See [Excel connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/), [ACE OLEDB connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/) if you might have files from Excel 2007 or later, and [Microsoft Jet connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-jet-ole-db-4-0/) if you don't have the [ACE drivers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) installed on the computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This connection string is for connecting to SQL server. SQL server database is not a file with certain file path. Knowing the server name and database name (in this example Database=CS) is enough. If you want to connect to Microsoft excel database, the standard connection string would be something like this (search for your proper version):

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\MyExcel.xls;
Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";
```

Comment: Thank you Ali, i understand what you are saying my problem is that where do we give the path for the database source? you have stated the below right but in my code i cannot see a reference to any databasel  like so Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\MyExcel.xls;

Comment: Ok so one quick question , is SQL server like a cloud based DB ? where you only need the server name and database name? so in other words it will automatically connect to the internet and search for the database?

Comment: SQL database is not a single file like Microsoft access or Microsoft Excel and so has not a direct path on windows drives. In a simple word, it is a complex mixture of files and settings where you can access it just by calling **server Name** and **database name**.  the word **Cloud** is not the definition of what I said. It is just a way to access to database services were those databases could be SQL server or not.

Comment: Makes sense Thank you ! can you give me some site from where i can learn that concept.. i am a noob to VBA programming..i searched but all are a bit complex for me..